# Is there any CSS file that has the following properties?

Tags: css

I am looking for CSS template that has the following properties:

1. Website title, menu bar and search box at the top of the page
2. Tree-based view for the the folders or sub pages on the left
3. body and the main content on the right

I googled about it but I did not get the exact properties. Please help me

Comment: If you search for css three column layout you will see tons of examples. They might not be exact but you have to use your development skills to make them so, it's pretty easy. The tree view will be harder and how it is done really depends on the functionality you require, so elaborate on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [CSS layout generator](http://csslayoutgenerator.com/). There are lots of different ones available, but I only linked the first one I found. I suggest that you try them and see what fits your requirements best, since you have not specified if you want a fixed or liquid layout or if any of the sections have a fixed width or height.

For the *tree* view, if you can use jQuery, I highly recommend the excellent [Dynatree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html) plugin which is one of the better tree plugins. I like it purely because it's so customizable.